# Display Div but at specific place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on one project which include a complex code and here is its simple prototype:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2" style="disply:none"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4" style="disply:none"></div>
<div id="5"></div>
<div id="6"></div>
<div id="7"></div>
<div id="8" style="disply:none"></div>

<button>Test</button>
```

Now, here is the scenario.

If I click on **Test button** then for example,
*div* with **id=4** should display but after the **id=7**.

**onclick** button, find id with 4 and display to incline - **these are done**.

Just finding a way to place these div **with id=4 after div with id=7**.

Both JavaScript and jQuery codes are welcome. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could actually manipulate the DOM using JS, or use CSS flexbox. Which are you more comfortable with?

Comment: Another question - what do you mean by "display"? Just the order they are drawn in the browser, or actually move div id=4 in the DOM to be after div id=7?

Comment: This is a simple scenario - based on click user might want to place id=4 div after id=5 div or other.

Comment: @Narxx: want to actually move the div.

Comment: As a side note... jQuery *is* Javascript. It's just a library written in Javascript.

Comment: @Azamantes: Yaah! I know that. But sometime we only need pure JS in code so I specifically mention. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using `insertAfter()`

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/be06q7de/

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#4').fadeIn().insertAfter($('#7'));
})
```

Comment: If div#7 include some JavaScript does it will run? I think because we are adding it dynamically.

Comment: Yes it will work, you can try to setup fiddle and test it .

Answer (score 1):

Try code below.

$('#4').insertAfter('#7').show()

Answer (score 0):

You may also use CSS with Flex and Order:

```css
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column
}
div[id] {
  order:-1;
  color:green
}
div#a4 {
  order:1;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="a1">1</div>
<div id="a2" >2</div>
<div id="a3">3</div>
<div id="a4" >4</div>
<div id="a5">5</div>
<div id="a6">6</div>
<div id="a7">7</div>
<div id="a8">8</div>
```

*Note: A single number used as ID name or Classname should not be used. see snippet below wiyh same CSS but your IDs*

```css
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column
}
div[id] {
  order:-1;
  color:green
}
div#4 {
  order:1;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2" >2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
<div id="4" >4</div>
<div id="5">5</div>
<div id="6">6</div>
<div id="7">7</div>
<div id="8">8</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *JQuery* to serve the purpose.

```js
$('#test').on('click',function(){
$('#4').insertAfter($('#7'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
<div id="4">4</div>
<div id="5">5</div>
<div id="6">6</div>
<div id="7">7</div>
<div id="8" >8</div>

<button id='test'>Test</button>
```

P.S: you can also make this code dynamic as per your needs by using them with classes and HTML5 attributes .